# save epoch time of on column into another column postgres

Tags: postgresql, epoch, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a table with two field in postgresql. One field is `creation_time` which is a timestamp with timezone and is filled with datetimes. Other field is `foo` which is filled by null values and I want to update this column by the epoch time of other column for each row.

How this is possible? I know that `extract(epoch)` can convert timestamp to epoch, but I don't know how to use it for my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. `foo` should be of type `bigint`.

```
UPDATE table SET foo = EXTRACT(epoch FROM creation_time)
```